# TSLint: forIn loop must be filtered

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, for-in-loop

I have an error with TSLINT on my project, about a forIn loop.
The error is the next one:

```
for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement
```

I have tried both solutions Object.prototype.hasOwnProerty.call(object, key) and object.hasOwnproperty(key), but I still have the error.

Here is the code:

```
const data = result.data
for (const key in data) {
  // Must use a if statement
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // code...
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea about what I am missing ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this by adding configuration in lint file.

reference :
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/forin/

OR
Second option:
Try this:

````
const data = result.data;
let key;
for (key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // code...
  }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for the first advice, but I can't because of project rules, I am not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

Actually, there was a single line outside the if statement handlebars, which uses the key...

NB for myself: make sure to check the statement scope.